# Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 14 fields in line 3, saw 57

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

What does the tokenizing mean in the the contex. I keep getting this error and I am unable to train my model. Please can somebody review my sample dataset and code to see where I have gone wrong ? For reference the traceback is as follows:

```
(keras_tf) G:\Python\integer_sequencing>python MyTest.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyTest.py", line 20, in <module>
    trainset= pd.read_csv('G:/Python/integer_sequencing/sample.csv')
  File "C:\Users\sarah\Anaconda3\envs\keras_tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\sarah\Anaconda3\envs\keras_tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 411, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\sarah\Anaconda3\envs\keras_tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1005, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\sarah\Anaconda3\envs\keras_tf\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1748, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 890, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:10862)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 912, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11138)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 966, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11884)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 953, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:11755)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2184, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:28765)
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 14 fields in line 3, saw 57


(keras_tf) G:\Python\integer_sequencing>
```

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import csv


trainset= pd.read_csv('G:/Python/integer_sequencing/sample.csv')
trainset.head()

testset= pd.read_csv('G:/Python/integer_sequencing/sample.csv')
testset.head()



Y_train = trainset.Sequence.apply(lambda x: str.split(x, ',')[-1] )
X_train = trainset.Sequence.apply(lambda x: str.split(x, ',')[:-1] )
trainset.head()

Y_test = testset.Sequence.apply(lambda x: str.split(x, ',')[-1] )
X_test = testset.Sequence.apply(lambda x: str.split(x, ',')[:-1] )
testset.head()

maxlen1 = int(round(trainset.Sequence.apply(len).max()))
maxlen2 = int(round(testset.Sequence.apply(len).max()))

X_train = pad_sequences(X_train, dtype='float', maxlen=maxlen1)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, dtype='float', maxlen=maxlen2)
#Y_train = pad_sequences(Y_train, dtype='float', maxlen=maxlen)


trainX, trainY = np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train)
testX, testY = np.array(X_test), np.array(Y_test)

trainX = trainX.reshape(trainX.shape + (1,))
testX = testX.reshape(testX.shape + (1,))

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(maxlen1, 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

# try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.summary()
model.fit(trainX, trainY, batch_size=32, epochs=5, verbose=0)

yhat = model.predict(trainX, verbose=0)
print(yhat)

#print(model.evaluate(X_test_rshp, y_test))
```

The training set that I am using can be downloaded from the [sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1llHJrs51OyAxtiFB4fQvyG4W2QkuvTyk)
I realize that there are similar questions and I tried using all the suggested method, but nothing seems to work in this case.

Comment: As a rule, you should include code as a representative [mcve]

Comment: thanks for letting me know. Added the code for reeference

Answer (score 0):

This is because your file (G:/Python/integer_sequencing/sample.csv) has a problem.
For example, some rows may have a different number of fields, meaning that a different number of comma in this case, as follows:

```
1. a, b, c
2. d, e, f
3. g, h, i, j # This third line has a problem.
4. k, l, m
```

Line 3 may have a value including ',', so it makes Pandas confused.
This is a common problem when you read a csv file :)